# How to take self portraits without a remote?

Tags: self-portrait

How can I take a self-portrait without using a remote?

My camera is a Canon Powershot SX210 IS. I do *not* have a remote, but I do have a tripod.

Comment: @mattdm Alright, I'll delete it out of here and create a new one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A timer.  Your camera should have a timer.  In fact your camera should have what it calls a 'FaceSelf-Timer' I believe.

In general, with a timer - you set you camera to take a picture after a predetermined set of time (like 2 or 10 seconds).  You press the button, hop in front of the camera, and it takes the picture after the number of seconds.

A'FaceSelf-Timer', a Canon feature, takes a picture a number of seconds (2 I believe) after it detects your face.  So you the camera in that mode, press the button, hop in front of the camera, it takes your picture two seconds after it detects your face.

Some general self portrait tips can be found [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/precise-focus-in-self-portraiture) and [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/tips-for-taking-headshot-self-portraits).

Comment: I did not know that some Canons have that feature. I've owned dozens of Canon point and shoots, never knew that.

Comment: Actually, I am referring to "manual focus"? How to achieve sharp eyes? Don't want to rely on auto-focus.

Comment: @Anisha ...uh what?Where does you question mention that? why would a remote matter?  In that case, just read http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/precise-focus-in-self-portraiture

Comment: I didn't think there was any need to mention that. Reason: Portraits are all about sharp eyes, I think. I'll look into the link. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to "[tether](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering)" your camera to your computer and control it that way... including snapping the shutter.

Not every camera will do this though.

Answer (score 2):

A Mirror can help you produced some interesting shots.
There's nothing that says "I'm a photographer" better than a shot of you taking a picture  :)

... Obviously, you'll probably be covering part of your face, so might not be what you want, but it's worth trying.